# Issues with class methods and attributes

Tags: python, class

I have a class with a few methods such as :

```py
class Module:

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.finite_state_machine = None

  def fsm(self, call_stack, module_name):
    pass
    # returns the finite state machine of a given module 

  def reading_file(path="default_path"):
    pass
    # opens and reads a file, return a list of line used for the next method

  def modules_dictionnary(self, lines):
    pass
    # returns the dictionnary of the modules
 
  def message_stack(lines, modules_dictionnary):
    pass
    # returns the call_stack the fsm method needs
```

The thing is I'm getting confused with methods, `self` keyword, classmethods, staticmethods etc

I would like for each class object say `m = Module('Alpha')` to have :

- a name (different for each object)
- a module dictionnary and a call_stack (shared among each object of this class
- a finite state machine (different for each object)

I tried running this in the builder : `self.fsm = self.fsm(message_stack(reading_file(), modules), modules_dictionary(reading_file()))` but it doesn't seem to work. I think I'm missing smething on the role of attributes and methods etc

Comment: If i understand correctly you are aiming towards a plugin-architecture. There are a lot of references, docs and tutorial videos on plugin architecture in python you can check out . 
Here is an interesting example by arjan codes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCE1bDoit9Q

Comment: What's the question? Where specifically are you having problems implementing the design?

Comment: I don't know how to have inside my class an attribute ```call_stack``` and ```module_dictionnary``` such that I could call ```reading_file()``` , then ```modules_fictionnary()``` and ```message_stack()``` in order to finally build my finite state machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialise dictionary and a call_stack in **init** function. They will be shared among all the objects of class. And for different value for each object you can create setter functions for name and final state machine and call them with required value. Something like this:

```
class Module:

 def __init__(self, dictionary, call_state):
     self.dictionary = dictionary
     self.call_state = call_state
     self.finite_state_machine = None
     self.name = None
 def set_name(self, name):
     self.name = name
     
 def set_fsm(self, fsm):
     self.finite_state_machine = fsm
     
dict_v = {}
call_state = ""
obj = Module(dict_v, call_state)
obj.set_name("xyq")
obj.set_fsm("testing")
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Tho here if I understand correctly, the dictionnary and the call stack have to be given as a paremeter when I instanciate the class object right ? Is there a way of building directly the dictionnary and the call stack within the class ? I though they could be class attirbutes hence being shared among all class objects

Comment: yes you can initialise them directly in __init__ function. But then you will not need to pass them when creating object.

Comment: I might be misreading the answer, but if you declare `self.dictionary = dictionary` in `__init__` then the dictionary is **not** shared among all instances of the class but individual for each instance. ... Edit: OK if you feed in the same dictionary to each instance then it's kind of shared. But it might be better to define the dictionary on class level.

Comment: see this code example
```
class Module:

 def __init__(self):
     self.dictionary = "dict"
     self.call_state = "state"
     self.finite_state_machine = None
     self.name = None
 def set_name(self, name):
     self.name = name
     
 def set_fsm(self, fsm):
     self.finite_state_machine = fsm

obj = Module()
```
obj.dictionary
obj2 = Module()
obj2.dictionary
Both will give same answer.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my edit I understand what is done here. Still I think that `dictionary` should be defined on class level. Then there's no need to define the dictionary from outside and to make sure that each instance gets exactly this one dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This answer sets the focus on the definition of the dictionary on class level.

```
class Module:
    dictionary = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_to_dictionary(self, key, value):
        Module.dictionary[key] = value


m1 = Module('a')
m1.add_to_dictionary('Monty', 'Python')
m2 = Module('b')
print(m2.dictionary)
```

This will give you `{'Monty': 'Python'}`.

You could even drop the `add_to_dictionary` method.

```
m2.dictionary['Eric'] = 'Idle'

# let's look at the content
print(m1.name)
print(m1.dictionary)
print(m2.name)
print(m2.dictionary)
```

With the result

```
a
{'Monty': 'Python', 'Eric': 'Idle'}
b
{'Monty': 'Python', 'Eric': 'Idle'}
```